# captcha Image link on html page

Tags: java, javascript, html

HI,
I am using a bot program in which i want to find out the link of captcha  image so that i can display on a Jframe.
When i am looking to page source their is no image link of captcha on it.It is generated on by javascript.
Please some body help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about if you inspect the dom using firebug?  It should show up then, then you can grab it dynamically with javascript if you need to.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but the captcha is there _for a reason_. If you need the content behind it, contact the publisher; they clearly don't want it grabbed by bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? It is likely that looking at the requirement rather than the technical solution would be the best option here. If you have a bot that wishes to spider information "protected" by a Captcha then contacting the providers and asking for direct access to the data would likely be a much better option that the cat & mouse game you will enter without the providers permission to access said content.

You could use a JavaScript interpreter to run the script. Java 6 comes with one [built in](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) or you could embed the complete HTML frame in a browser for the manual part.